# jQuery parseJSON syntax error ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

I'm using jquery 1.8.2 doing an ajax call in a simple ASP.NET app. Everything work fines on localhost using the built in VS web dev server. When I put the web site on IIS I get a generic error:

```
Message: Syntax error
Line: 514
Char: 4
Code: 0
URI: http://123.123.123.123/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js
```

This is from my call to:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(val);
```

Here's what at that location in the jquery source:

```
parseJSON: function( data ) {
if ( !data || typeof data !== "string") {
    return null;
}

// Make sure leading/trailing whitespace is removed (IE can't handle it)
data = jQuery.trim( data );

// Attempt to parse using the native JSON parser first
if ( window.JSON && window.JSON.parse ) {
    return window.JSON.parse( data );  <<< LINE 514
}

...(rest of jquery source)
```

Any ideas? Like I said, works fine locally.

Comment: That's just a snippet from the jquery source code, specifically the line where it errors. I didn't past the whole thing in. I added ... to make this clearer.

Comment: A would suggest you load up fiddler to look at the raw traffic and see exactly what is coming back.

Comment: Thanks. I did do a simple alert to see what "val" was. Locally it comes back with a normal string that then goes onto the get parsed into json. On the web server though it comes back with, wait for it... "C", the capital letter C. This is using the same exact input to the process. C?

Comment: Don't just do an alert. Request the actual page (*the one the ajax uses*) in your browser and see what it brings back (*the source code*).

Comment: You need to look at the raw JSON data that comes back. Your alert won't show you everything you need, especially if an error message of any sort is getting sent back.

Comment: Thanks, this level of javascript/jquery is new to me. How would I do that? View source after clicking the Submit btn just shows the original code. (BTW chumkiu - I tried your suggestion, no luck) This is after an jquery ajax call too.

Comment: @KaneJeeves the problem is not javascript (or jquery source code), but the var `val`. How you build it?

Comment: It's just a string equivalent of json data. The parseJSON is supposed to turn it onto an actual object. For example: {"SpecialCase":"No info found"} this is just a string that comes back from the web service ajax calls. The info in it has nothing to do with anything. So this same exact string works fine locally, comes back as C on the server. Calling a PageMethod if that matters, that returns this string.

Comment: @KaneJeeves try to understand why val is "C" on server side. But, I repeat myself, jquery source code has nothing to do here :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oy, Stupid programmer error. The C was the first letter from an error message my own code generated. "Component not found". In this case a file wasn't being loaded because of Server Mappath problems. The upshot I'm learning is that jQuery, JSON, jTemplates, etc are all relatively straightforward. It's the dev environment, namely ASP.NET and Visual Studio 2010 that get in the way WAY more than the languages themselves.  Thanks all for the great input.